# Defining functions and index in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, indexing

I have 2 questions in Postgres:

1. How can I define(create) these functions?

   - AnyElement(s): which returns any element.
   - FirstElement(s): which returns the first element.
   - lastElement(s): which returns the last element.
   - ithElement(s): which returns the ith element.
   - currentElement(s): which returns current element.
2. How can I define(create) index?

Comment: What exactly is "current element" supposed to mean? First and last can be retrieved using `min()` and `max()`. For the "n-th" element see [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks a lot of detail, for example:

- What are you trying to achieve?
- What have you already tried?

Also, reading postgreSQL documentation is essential. Your second question, for example, is a straight forward answer using that documentation:
[PostgreSQL Create Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-pseudo.html)

I would probable start by looking exactly into that for your questions:
[PostgreSQL documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/index.html)